# missing default value on parmeter

Tags: c++

I keep getting this error.

**error: missing default argument on parmeter 'm'**

Can please someone explain why do I get this? And how to fix it?

```
   int func(vector<int>& arr, int l, int r,int res = 0,unordered_map<int,int>& m)
    {
    if (l > r) 
    { 
        m[res] ++;;
        return; 
    } 
  
    // Subset including arr[l] 
    func(arr, l+1, r, res || arr[l],m); 
  
    // Subset excluding arr[l] 
    func(arr, l+1, r, res,m); 
    }
    
    int subarrayBitwiseORs(vector<int>& arr) {
         unordered_map<int,int> m;
         func(arr, 0, arr.size() - 1,0, m);
         return (m.end()--)->first;
      
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put a parameter without a default value after a parameter with a default value. So, you can fix it like this:

`int func(vector<int>& arr, int l, int r, unordered_map<int,int>& m, int res = 0)`